# Using win32com.client to Read MS Word Table

Tags: python, ms-word, office365, win32com, office-automation

I have a MS Word document (Microsoft 365) that I want to update via python using the win32com.client module. Within the .docx file, some tables have been inserted and there are cells containing text values within those tables, that I want to update. I've been testing how to read through the table using win32com. For example:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True

doc = word.Documents.Open(r"path_to_my_doc")

doc = word.ActiveDocument

table = doc.Tables(2)

for row in range(1,table.Rows.Count + 1):
    for col in range(1,table.Columns.Count + 1):
        print(table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text)
```

The above code works fine when reading through a table that has equal rows and columns and no merged or split cells. The issue I run into is where a table has merged cells or split cells. The code will start reading through the table, but when it hits a row that has more or less cells than the last row, it produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\em\vic\mtb\Local\MTB_Scripts\Testing_Area\mmacrae\IOR\2022Nov_updates\script\win32com_word.py", line 41, in <module>
    table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text = table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text
  File "E:\sw_nt\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x5\Table.py", line 50, in Cell
    , Column)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Word', u'The requested member of the collection does not exist.', u'wdmain11.chm', 25421, -2146822347), None)
```

Here is a screenshot of the word document I have been testing on that contains 3 tables.

[image]

The first table has equal columns along each row. When I run the code on that table, it will print our the cells text values with no errors. When I run the code on the second 2 tables, where I had split a few cells so that there are odd numbers of columns for each row, I receive the error.

After a lot of testing, I feel like these merged or split cells are causing the issue. I've been googling around to see if this issue has come up and I can't find anything there or here on Stack. Hoping for some suggestions on how to handle these tables and code.

Comment: Why not enumerate rows and enumerate cells for each row?

Answer (score 2):

With the OP's structure, change the iteration range on the inner loop:

```
for row in range(1,table.Rows.Count+1):
    for col in range(1,table.Rows(row).Cells.Count+1):
        print(table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text)
```

But, it can be somewhat cleaner to use Python's iteration capabilities:

```
for rw in table.Rows:
    for cl in rw.Cells:
        print(cl.Range.Text)
```

a by-product of which is that you can't run off the end of a range.